# How do I make SHIFT+Backspace into back tab in my Vimrc?

Tags: vim

In Vimrc...

I want shift+backspace to go back 1 tab. (opposite of tab)

Comment: Is this gvim or vim at the terminal? Because most terminals don't send a code for shift-backspace that's distinguishable from the one for backspace.

Comment: I just want to go backwards by 1 tab space. I dont' care how it's done. I'm on Mac.

Comment: What's the opposite of a tab?

Comment: The opposite of tab is tab in the other direction.

Comment: Do you want to do this in insert or normal mode?  The solution I posted is for normal mode, the solution posted by tungd is for insert mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can achieve "one tab backwards" with plain backspace with:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Anyway if this did not work, you can use `<c-d>` (that's Ctrl + D) or mapping any key to this. I use Shift + Tab in insert mode:

```
inoremap <s-tab> <c-d>
```